# .htaccess block hidden directories except one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to allow access to a folder called .well-known but I've found this rule that blocks hidden directories;

```
# block hidden directories
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

Obviously there's a reason why this was added (I inherited the code) but I was wondering if I could keep this rule but add an exception for the .well-known folder?

Comment: Hi! I am not a regex expert therefore, I just wanted to make sure that in your rule, you are preventing directories as well as files starting with `.` right?  because as far as my understandings are, your rule state that `^` any File `|` or `/` directory starting with `\.`. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed! You need to include a Rewrite Condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
```

Put this before the actual `RewriteRule`, this condition basically tells the server NOT to hide the `.well-known` folder.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! :)

Comment: No problem @SamPearson glad I could help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that others know the solution worked :)

Comment: Hello!

I'm now getting this error;

You don't have permission to access /index.php/.well-known/pki-validation/randomstring.txt on this server. 

Do I need to amend the previous answer to do fix this? 

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @SamPearson they above answer is just for stopping the `.well-known` directory from being hidden. Accessing it is different and therefore should be a different question :) But you should be able to achieve this by using `order,deny,allow` and allowing access.

Comment: Hi Joe! I am not a regex expert therefore, I just wanted to make sure that in above rule of @SamPearson , he is preventing directories as well as files starting with `.` right?  because as far as my understandings are, his rule states that `^` any File `|` or `/` directory starting with `\.`. Is that right?

Comment: @SamPearson in continue in apache.conf: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourdomain/
    <Directory ~ "/\.(?!well-known\/)">
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>